# How to handle mango puree going stale in mousse

Tags: mousse, mango

I made a mango mousse cake using the recipe here: https://www.womanscribbles.net/mango-mousse-cake/
Turned out nice, but after two days the mango puree was tasting stale. How can i counter this?

Comment: By mango puree you mean the gel that goes on top? Or the puree that you used to make the mousse and the gel?

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza i mean the puree content that goes into the mousse and gel

Comment: Oh. You shouldn't keep it for that long, homemade fruit purees don't have any preservatives and weren't made in optimal conditions for having a longer shelf life. You make it, and use it for your desert and if you have leftovers you need to turn your puree into something else that can be consumed quickly or has longer shelf life (like a chutney or a preserve). For the next time you might be able to prolong shelf life to 1 or 2 days by adding lemon juice (with vitamin C, which is a natural antioxidant), but for this one there is nothing you can do.